# How to copy a graph using boost c++?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have a problem copying a graph using boost? My code is given below: It doesn't let me to create IndexMap as a type.

```
template <class Graph>
int abc(Graph& G){

    typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor NodeID;

    typedef map<size_t, NodeID> IndexMap; //It doesn't let me to create NodeID type

    typedef map<NodeID, size_t> IndexMap;

    IndexMap mapIndex;

    associative_property_map<IndexMap> propmapIndex(mapIndex);

    Graph g1, g2;

    int i=0;
    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, g2, Graph)
    {
       put(propmapIndex, v, i++);
    }

    g1.clear();
    copy_graph( g2, g1, vertex_index_map( propmapIndex ) );
    g2.clear();

}

int main(){

    typedef adjacency_list<listS, vecS, undirectedS, 
        WeightProperty, property<edge_color_t, default_color_type>  MyGraphType;
    typename graph_traits<MyGraphType>::adjacency_iterator ai, ai_end;

    typename graph_traits<MyGraphType>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
    ...
    ...

    MyGraphType G;
    ... //addition of vertices and edges
    abc(G);

}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just in case no-one knows a definite answer here, I've had great success in asking on `boost-users` in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess

```
typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor NodeID;
```

should be

```
typedef typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor NodeID;
```

The upper variant is a declaration of a variable `NodeID` of type `graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor`, while the latter is a typedef for the same type.

Comment: Thanks !! That problem is fixed. But it is still giving me problem in BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, g2, Graph).

Comment: @user3236678 Since `Graph` is a dependent name you need to use BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T (it uses `typename` inside the macro).